# Why is there an offset difference with overlay placement or bounds V3 from V2?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, overlay, offset

I have many (100s) of maps in a databse made for V2. Now migrating to V3 and they're all offeset by quite a long way than they were before.
Have I done something wrong? Or is there a bug or difference that I have to correct? I don't really want to have to re-make all my maps for the new version.

See an example here: http://www.trebrown.com/plant_info_temp.php?species=Bismarckia+nobilis+sp.+silver Scroll down the page to se the map, and then zoom out 1 or 2 stops, you'll then see the Madagascar map out in the middle of the Indian ocean.

Here's my code:

```
var overlay;
TrebrownOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
function initialize() {
    var marker;
    var sp_id = "353";
    function createMarker(point,infowindow) {
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: point, map: map, title:"" });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
      });
      return marker;
     }
   var localitiy = new google.maps.LatLng(-19.311144, 46.362305);
   var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 5,
      center: localitiy,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
      var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.371767300523032, 33.1787109375);
      var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(-10.83330598364249, 59.5458984375);
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);
      var srcImage = 'http://www.trebrown.com/images/maps/bismarckia-nobilis.png';
      overlay = new TrebrownOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
}
function TrebrownOverlay(bounds, image, map) {
  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;
  this.div_ = null;
  this.setMap(map);
}
TrebrownOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.appendChild(img);
  this.div_ = div;
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
}
TrebrownOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());
  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
}
TrebrownOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a CSS-issue, there is a interaction with the style of the parent-element of `#map-canvas`

remove the format `text-align: right;` from the parent `div.morespace`

or override it by applying the style `text-align:left` for `#map-canvas`